# Retrieve id from cell with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to retrive the `id` of a `<td>` having only the text content of the `<td>`.

For example:

```
.....
<tr>
    <td id='hey'>Hello world!</td>
</tr>
....
```

If I know the text "Hello world", is it possible to retrive the `id` of the `<td>`?

/***********/
Thanks to all guys! I will try the solutions offered as soon as possible!! Just to explain i was working with OBIEE 11g and i was trying to write a script to add format condition to grand total that is not supported. Till now i came up with this solution:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var threshold = 10; // set the threshold
/*** Definizione colonne da formattare ***/
/*** Partire da 0 ***/
var colonneFormattate = new Array(2);
colonneFormattate[0] = 0;
colonneFormattate[1] = 2;
/************************************************/
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('PTDT');
for(var td =0; td < colonneFormattate.length;td++){
    var amount = (tds[colonneFormattate[td]].innerHTML.replace("€","")).replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
    //alert(colonneFormattate[td]);
    var lungh = amount.indexOf(",");
            var novirgole = amount.substring(0,lungh);
            var novirgole = novirgole.replace(/\./g,"");
    var num = parseInt(novirgole);
    if(num > threshold){
        tds[colonneFormattate[td]].style.color = "green";
    }else{
        tds[colonneFormattate[td]].style.color = "red";
    }
}
</script>
```

So in this case the grand total will be coloured if the number is higher then threshold.
I ask your help to try to define the column to search in an array to make it more simple for the user. I mean if the user want to format the column named Turnover, it will add in the script the column that he needs.

I will try your suggestion!
And i will let you know!

Cheers!

Comment: Why yes, it is indeed possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Who is downvoting everything?

Comment: LOL just watched everyone get a sympathy upvote. one by one they all changed to zeros, but then it got down to Ryan, and he just got another downvote. Oh it did make me chuckle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var tdarr = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < tdarr.length; i++) {
    if (tdarr[i].innerHTML === "Hello world!") {
        alert(tdarr[i].id);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKSUp/)

Comment: @Downvoter: What's wrong with this solution? You should always explain that when you downvote.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution, it only matches an exact match and not just contains the text, this search does not stop after the first match but would continue until there are no more elements to search through

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id='hey'>Hello world!</td>
            <td id='hey2'>Hello world 2!</td>
            <td id='hey3'>Hello world 3!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var search = "Hello world!";

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("td"), function (td) {
    if (td.textContent === search) {
        alert(td.id);
    }
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/CBjVv/)

If you want a solution the searches within the text and stops after the first match then you can do this

```
var search = "Hello world!";

Array.prototype.some.call(document.getElementsByTagName("td"), function (td) {
    if (td.textContent.indexOf(search) !== -1) {
        alert(td.id);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/WJfcL/)

Comment: Care to explain the down vote? Did I misinterpret the question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdp6t/)

```
var searchString = "Hello world!";
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

[].forEach.call(tds, function (td) {
    if (td.textContent.indexOf(searchString) > -1) { // For exact match use td.textContent === searchString 
        alert(td.id);
    }
});
```

See compatibility for:

- [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)

Comment: How would you do it without jQuery?

Comment: [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not jQuery

Comment: @MMM He is not looking for Jquery, just javascript

Comment: @Ryan I dint see the tag closely hence wrote it as jquery initially... Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @PSCoder: Exactly, I was responding to Ryan who seems to think you've used jQuery... Unless you did initially.

Comment: @MMM no i initially wrote it in jquery with `:Contains` later @Ryan pointed out.. :) Thanks guys

Comment: +1 Though a compatibility patch for `.forEach()` and `.textContent` may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Right, my "no JQuery" is pretty rough but here goes:

```
var matchedId;

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
   var element = elements[i];
   if(element.innerHTML.indexOf("Hello world!") != -1){
      matchedId = element.id;
      break;
   }
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FfaMx/1/)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery offers the `:contains` selector:

```
$('td:contains("Hello world!")')[0].id
```

Without that, though, you'd need to do it manually:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var id;

outer: for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    var td = tds[i];

    for(var j = 0; j < td.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var child = td.childNodes[j];

        if(child.nodeType === 3 && child.nodeValue.indexOf('Hello world!') !== -1) {
            id = td.id;
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you don't want the same level of compatibility as `:contains`, just check `td.textContent.indexOf('Hello, world!')` instead.

Comment: Why the downvotes on... everything else? They're perfectly right for exact matches. (I only used `indexOf` because of the exclamation mark anyways.)

Answer (score 0):

OK guys!
Thanks to all of you, i had used your code, and achieved my goal in this way:

```
for(var td =0; td < tds.length;td++){
    //alert(tds[td].textContent);
    if(tds[td].textContent == colonna[0]){
        var id = tds[td].id;
        var numcol = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("_")+1,id.length);
        colonna[4] = parseInt(numcol);
        td = tds.length;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the suggestion!!

Cheers!